# Partial derivatives inverse question

Tags: calculus

If $ \partial u/\partial v=a $, then $ \partial v/\partial u=1/a$?

Comment: Try setting $a=0$.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Functions of a Single Variable**

For functions of one variable, if $y=f(x)$ is strictly monotone and differentiable on an interval, and $f'(x)\ne 0$ in that interval, then the inverse function $x=f^{-1}(y)$ is also strictly monotone and differentiable in the corresponding interval and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}}\tag 1$$

---

**EXAMPLE:**

Suppose $y=\sin(x)$ for $x\in (-\pi/2,\pi,2)$.  Note that the sine function is monotone and differentiable on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x)$ and $\cos(x)\ne 0$.

The inverse function, call it $x=\arcsin(y)$ for $y\in (-1,1)$, is  therefore monotone and its derivative is

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Therefore, we have $\frac{d\,\arcsin(y)}{dy}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$.

---

**Functions of a Two Variables**

The relationship in $(1)$ does ***not*** apply, in general, to functions of more than one variable.  As an example, examine the transformation of Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ to polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$ as given by

$$\begin{align}
\rho &=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\\\
\phi &=\operatorname{arctan2}(y,x)
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
x&=\rho \cos(\phi)\\\\
y&=\rho \sin(\phi)
\end{align}$$

We examine the relationship between $\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho}$ to see if $(1)$ holds. Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial x}&=\frac{x}{\rho}\\\\
& =\cos(\phi)\\\\
&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial x}\ne \frac{1}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho}}$ and $(1)$ does not hold (unless $y=0$).

Instead of the relationship $(1)$ holding, we have instead

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \rho} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

whereupon matrix inversion becomes

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \rho} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}  =\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \tag 2\end{equation}$$

Note that $(2)$ is the analog of $(1)$ and applies whenever a transformation and its inverse exists and is prescribed by differentiable functions.  Moreover, it can be generalized to any number of variables.

Comment: I think you are incorrect as to whether (1) holds with functions of more than one variable.  It is true that (1) only holds for *total* derivatives, which is what you proved.  However, (1) holds just fine for the multivariate case.

In your example $x = \rho \cos(\theta)$.  So then, by differentiation, $dx = -\rho \sin(\theta)\,d\theta + \cos(\theta)\,d\rho$.  Therefore, $$ \frac{dx}{d\rho} = -\rho \sin(\theta) \frac{d\theta}{d\rho} + \cos(\theta) $$

Comment: @johnnyb What are you talking about??  Equation $(1)$ holds for single variables.  But for partial derivatives, it is not in general true that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}=\frac1{\frac{\partial v}{\partial u}}$

Comment: @johnnyb  In your comment, you have assumed that $\theta$ and $\rho$ are dependent variables.  That is not generally the case.

Comment: As to your first comment, I was talking about the fact that (1) holds for multiple variables, <i>as long as you are dealing in total differentials</i>.  I agree that it does not hold for partials, as the partial notation is somewhat nonsensical anyway (i.e., there is not a distinct "partial u".  There are multiple "partial u"s.  That's why you can't invert the ratio).

Comment: As to your second comment, I don't think I've made any such assumption.  However, if I did, I would be greatly appreciative if you can show me an example of where the formula as I gave it breaks down because of variable dependence, where it doesn't also break down in the original equation.  That would help my thinking a lot.

Comment: @johnnyb You wrote "as the partial notation is somewhat nonsensical anyway."  Partial derivatives are well defined, so your statement is simply unfounded.  I showed that (i) under the stated assumptions $y'(x)=1/x'(y)$, (ii) it is not in general true that when $(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)$ that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is the reciprocal of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$, and (iii) that the relationship in equation $(1)$ has as a generalization $(2)$.

Comment: @johnnyb In your comment, you wrote "$\frac{dx}{d\rho}=-\rho\sin(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{d\rho}+\cos(\theta)$," whereby you are tacitly suggesting that the independent variables $\rho$ and $\theta$ are related.  If so, we are back to a single variable problem where $x$ depends on $\rho$.

Comment: I agree with your points (i), (ii), and (iii) above.  I also agree that the concept of partial derivatives are well-defined; it is the *notation* that is non-sensical.

Comment: That's why so many books opt for $f_x$ instead of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.  The reason why you can't treat $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as a fraction isn't because there is something fundamentally incompatible with treating differentials as fractions, but because the fraction has information *about* the numerator *in* the denominator.  That's why the notation is non-sensical.  If you actually separated out the information it would be workable as a fraction.  I'm currently working on a paper on this.

Comment: "you are tacitly suggesting that the independent variables ρ and θ are related"

I don't think so, though I could be mistaken.  I'm saying that the *ratio* of dx and $d\rho$ is dependent on $\rho$ and $\theta$.  The equation does not depend on $\rho$ and $\theta$ being dependent on each other.

Comment: As this thread is getting long, we should probably move this to chat.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71558/discussion-of-differentials-as-ratios

Comment: You have written $\frac{d\rho}{d\theta}$.  If these are independent, then that derivative is $0$ and its appearance is superfluous.  As far as notation, it's only notation.  Neither a total derivative $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ nor a partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ is a fraction.  So, I'm not sure as to the point you're trying to make regarding fractions.

Comment: @MarkViola It's an interesting answer, +1 :) . What is the result that you mentioned in equation 2 called. Can you provide me with some reference?

Comment: @RishabhJain, the equation right before (2) follows from the chain rule. For, if $(\rho, \phi) = P(x, y)$ is the change of variables to polar coordinates, and $(x, y) = C(\rho, \phi)$ the change of variables to Cartesian, then $C\circ P = id$ (on a properly selected domain). Taking the differential of both sides of this identity yields the equation right before (2).