# Can I give a counterexample of partial derivatives inverse question like this?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I just want to find an example for  $$\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s} \neq \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x}}$$

Book and other post like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1744211/728591) are all using Jacobian matrices.

They all using the variable $y$, that equation be like $x=f\Big(s(x,y),t(x,y)\Big)$

I'm wonder whether the below way is right, just removed the variable $y$.

let $x=f(s(x),t(x))$.

so we will have $$1 = \frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $$$$= \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{ds}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\cdot \frac{dt}{dx} $$$$= \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} $$$$= \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$$

$$1 - \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial s}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} $$
So, it should be not always be zero, proved.

Is my proof correct?